# How to combine two values of same property in object by using comma separator?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have scenario to combine the values of same property with seperator. Is it possible. My json structure is like this:

```
{
  "name": "aa",
  "name": "bb",
  "name1": "cc",
  "name2": "dd"
}
```

I  want to display the value of key (name) as `aa, bb`.

Comment: Do `console.log` this object and check its properties.. You will enjoy it..

Comment: can not use the same key inside an object if u use the last value only u can get cz it will replace the old one

Comment: @gayathri ok.but if i have an  array of strings ["aa","bb"],then i need to display them in a table row with seperator is it possible.

Comment: Yes. it is possible

Comment: @VivekSingh ok Can plz tell how it will be

Comment: joining: `["aa","bb"].join(', ')` with a space, `["aa","bb"].join()` without.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?
I am getting the whole response but for doing ng-repeat i need to see if the recruiters has same job id then they need to be placed in same row separated with comma

Comment: so your array have unique ID ryt [ {
     "name":"aa",'id'' : 1 } ,  {
     "name":"bb", "id" : 2} ] like this ?

Comment: @gayathri yes I have unique id

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the json to get required solution

```
var obj = [
  { key : 'name'     , value : 'foo' },
  { key : 'name'     , value : 'bar' },
  { key : 'name1', value : 'baz' }
];
values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
  if (obj[i].key === 'name')
  {
      values.push(obj[i].value);
  }
}

console.log(values.join());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same key `name` in your JSON.

This does not make sense. Instead you can try this approach:

Create unique keys in your JSON, like,

```
    var mockDataForThisTest = "json=" + encodeURI(JSON.stringify([
        {
    "name":"aa",
    "name0":"bb",
    "name1":"cc",
    "name2":"dd"},

    ]));
```

Then you need to load the JSON in a `$scope` variable from your `controller`

```
function nameCtrl($scope, $http) {

$scope.names= [];

$scope.loadNames = function() {
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: mockDataForThisTest

    }).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.names= data;
    });

};
}
```

Then in the html page,

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
    {{name.name}}
    <span>&#44;</span>
    {{name.name0}}
    <span>&#44;</span>
    {{name.name1}}
    <span>&#44;</span>
    {{name.name2}}

</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Create filter like this

```
app.filter('join', function () {
    return function join(array, separator, prop) {
        if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
            return array; // if not array return original - can also throw error
        }

        return (!!prop ? array.map(function (item) {
           return item[prop];
        }) : array).join(separator);
    };
});
```

Use in template like this

```
<span>{{var1 | var2 | join:', ' }}</span>
```

Creating filter enables you to use it any times. You will have to just place variables that you want to join by separator in place of `var1` and `var2`.

Regards.